# Apache / php7.4-fpm: "malformed URL". Your Browser sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: apache-2.2, php-fpm

I'm configuring an apache vhost to use php7.4-fpm.

Any requests to the host yield a '400 Bad Request' response.

The vhost definition is as follows:

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test.localdev
    Servername wootest.localdev


    <Directory /var/www/test.localdev>
            AllowOverride none
            FallbackResource /index.php
            Require all granted
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    </Directory>

    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$  unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi:/var/www/test.localdev/
    DirectoryIndex index.php /index.php


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test.localdev.error-log


    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test.localdev.access-log combined
```

The error exists no matter which web client makes a request, so I can most probably rule out client-side issues.